# Control the scale of an object by another parameter (length of another object)?

Tags: animation, drivers

I have this lever:

[image]

When I move that selected face (of the cube) in a **local** way on the X axis...

[image]

I want that parameter to control the scale of the sphere (when the length of the lever is short, the size of the sphere is small, when it's big, the size of the sphere is big)... BUT...

[image]

While also retaining the sphere on the lever.

Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope i understood you right, so you want this:

[image]

this can be done with drivers.

This is how e.g. my scale x/y/z driver of the sphere looks like:

[image]

Input is the cube's x-location and i just use that as scale value.

blend file: [image]

To add a driver just right-click on the property you want to drive and choose "add driver".

A driver works like this: you have an input variable (or more or none) and with these you can "drive"/change that value where you put the driver in.

e.g.

[image]

here my input variable is again the x-location of my cube.

With this i change the z-location of my sphere with this:

var + .8

var is the x-location (of course i could have renamed it) and i add .8 to it, because it has some "starting position" because it "sits" on the lever.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want, thank you! I will explore drivers.

Comment: I just noticed you provided a lot more detail, thanks a lot! I will try to see how to add drivers and then add those settings. Thank you for the blend file as well, so helpful!

Comment: you are welcome. If you don't understand something, just ask - then i will improve my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I am a bit confused how you were able to add a driver to that specific face x location on the plane. When I move it with G -> X, and I right click the X parameter, I don't find a "Add Driver" setting.

Comment: honestly, i did not really understand what you meant with face x location - i just used the x location of my cube to drive the other values. You can add a driver buy right clicking over the property (e.g. z scale value) and then "add driver"

Comment: Sorry I meant that the length of the cube was growing but not on both sides, on one side only, which is what I wanted. I figured out that you simply moved the object's anchor point to that opposite face, and scaled in local space. Brilliant!

Comment: yes, that did the trick ;) the problem is, that if you are a bit more experienced, you sometimes "forget" the "gotchas" you made earlier...